# bitly not shortening url on server machine

Tags: php, url-shortener

I am using the bitbly API to shorten urls.

here is a snippet of the PHP code I am using.

```
<?php
        $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version='.$version.'&longurl='.urlencode($url).'&login='.$login.'&apikey='.$appkey.'&format='.$format;

        //The above string evaluates to:
http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=&longurl=http://real.address.replace&login=myname&apikey=A_key_provided_by_bitbly&format=json

        $response = file_get_contents($bitly);

        $json = @json_decode($response,true);
}
```

When I invoke this, I get the following JSON response:

```
{"errorCode": 500, "errorMessage": "MISSING_ARG_APIKEY", "results": null, "statusCode": ""}
```

I can't for the life of me, understand why bitly is returning that error - especially since I am passing the api key - what gives?

Comment: As a side note, the actual name of the service is bit.ly.

Comment: @pt2ph8: So the url should be something like: http://bit.ly/shorten?version..... Is that what you mean?

Comment: Your answer below talks about the wrong capitalisation of a query parameter - I get that.  My question is regards the side note comment you made about the name of the service. You seem to be suggesting that the url I use in making the call is incorrect - this is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't mean that. I was referring to the question's title (which now has been corrected anyway). Did you try to change the parameter name? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is `apiKey`, not `apikey`.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out the longurl parameter should also be longUrl - it works now!